# NameError: name 'pil_mask' is not defined

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, image-augmentation

This is my code. I have defined various operations like this:

```
def identity(pil_img, pil_mask, _):
    return pil_img, pil_mask

def autocontrast(pil_img, pil_mask, _):
    return ImageOps.autocontrast(pil_img), pil_mask


def equalize(pil_img, pil_mask, _):
    return ImageOps.equalize(pil_img), pil_mask



def rotate(pil_img, pil_mask, level):
    degrees = int_parameter(level, min_max_vals.rotate.max)
    if np.random.uniform() > 0.5:
        degrees = -degrees
    return pil_img.rotate(degrees, resample=Image.BILINEAR), pil_mask.rotate(degrees, resample=Image.BILINEAR)
```

like the above.

Now I want to use the PRIME augmentation (PRImitives of Maximum Entropy) :

but I am getting an error:

```
    aug_x += fn(x_tensor, pil_mask, _) * mask_t[:, i] * weight
NameError: name 'pil_mask' is not defined
```

```
and this is the PRIME code:

augmentations = [
    (identity, 1.0)
    ]
class PRIMEAugModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.augmentations = augmentations
        self.num_transforms = len(augmentations)


    def forward(self, x, mask_t):
        x_tensor = torch.from_numpy(x)
        aug_x = torch.zeros_like(x_tensor)
        for i in range(self.num_transforms):
            fn, weight = self.augmentations[i]
            if fn.__name__ == 'identity':
                aug_x += fn(x_tensor, pil_mask, _) * mask_t[:, i] * weight
            else:
                aug_x += fn(x_tensor, pil_mask) * mask_t[:, i] * weight
        return aug_x
```

I am confused where and how should I define PIL_mask

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet above, pil_mask is created as a PIL Image, then converted to a NumPy array (pil_mask_np). You can now use pil_mask_np wherever you need it in your code.

```
 import torch
 import numpy as np
 import PIL.Image as Image
    
 def identity(x_tensor, pil_mask, _):
    return x_tensor

 augmentations = [
   (identity, 1.0)
]

    pil_mask = Image.new('L', (256, 256), color=0)
pil_mask_np = np.array(pil_mask)

    class PRIMEAugModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.augmentations = augmentations
        self.num_transforms = len(augmentations)


    def forward(self, x, mask_t):
        x_tensor = torch.from_numpy(x)
        aug_x = torch.zeros_like(x_tensor)
        for i in range(self.num_transforms):
            fn, weight = self.augmentations[i]
            if fn.__name__ == 'identity':
                aug_x += fn(x_tensor, pil_mask_np, _) * mask_t[:, i] * weight
            else:
                aug_x += fn(x_tensor, pil_mask_np) * mask_t[:, i] * weight
        return aug_x
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).